# Nested IF condition behaving unexpectedly

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a couple of IF conditions as follows.

```
      if (globals.chatroomInfoMap.containsKey(chatroomID)) {
        if (messageData['name'] != null) {
          globals.chatroomInfoMap[chatroomID].name =
              messageData['name'];
              print('object ${globals.chatroomInfoMap[chatroomID].name}');
        }
        print('1');
        if (messageData['timestamp'] != null) {
          globals.chatroomInfoMap[chatroomID].timestamp =
              messageData['timestamp'];
              print('object ${globals.chatroomInfoMap[chatroomID].timestamp}');
        }
        print('2');
        if (messageData['members'] != null) {
          globals.chatroomInfoMap[chatroomID].members =
              messageData['members'];
              print('object ${globals.chatroomInfoMap[chatroomID].members}');
        }
        print('3');
        if (messageData['slogan'] != null) {
          globals.chatroomInfoMap[chatroomID].slogan =
              messageData['slogan'];
              print('object ${globals.chatroomInfoMap[chatroomID].slogan}');
        }
        print('object here');
      }
```

In the output, I could only see the following

> I/flutter (25612): object OtherRoom!!@
>
> I/flutter (25612): 1

So what we see is the print from the print inside second IF statement and the next line is '1' from the print after that. Then there is debug prints at all. I wonder what sorcery is this ? I tried the same thing in Dartpad, to make sure I am not using the syntax properly.

Code used in Dartpad:

```
main() {
  final Map<String, dynamic> messageData = {
    'slogan': 'buhuhu1',
    'chatroomID': 'H8j0EHhu2QpicgFDGXYZ',
    'mode': 'chatroom - update',
    'name': 'OtherRoom@!',
    'timestamp': '2019-02-23T17:12:12.000Z',
    'click_action': 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
    'members': ["fb7TfdFvl7tWgtSldgHs", "8kG2kE4jBkPs2qwt7GYA"]
  };
  final Map<String, dynamic> global = {'H8j0EHhu2QpicgFDGXYZ': 'something'};

  if (global.containsKey(messageData['chatroomID'])) {
    if (messageData['name'] != null) {
      print('here 1');
    }
    print('here');
    if (messageData['timestamp'] != null) {
      print('here 2');
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

> here 1
>
> here
>
> here 2

Can you please help me understand what I am missing? I am sure its some very stupid mistake.

Comment: Can't you debug your code and step through it, line by line, evaluate variables, and the like?

Comment: I am using VS Code and using Dart - Flutter framework to develop mobile apps. I do not know how to debug other than putting Print statements in between.

Comment: @vzurd https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/vs-code#running-and-debugging

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I used the debug, and it seems to come out of the whole thing after  if (messageData['timestamp'] != null) {... .

Comment: I got the problem. The timestamp is of a different datatype. I wonder why it didn't throw an error. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I got the problem. The timestamp is of a different datatype. I wonder why it didn't throw an error. Thanks for your help.